# Is it possible to choose language for spell check for each individual mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, dictionary, spellcheck

I commonly write mails in different languages and would like to have the spell checker function with that. Previously I have been using Thunderbird on both my macs and linux machines, but recently I have decided to give up on Thunderbird and try Mail.app instead (since Thunderbird isn't actively developed and apparently lagging behind).

In thunderbird you can have a combobox that allows you to choose a dictionary with which the software checks spelling. Is something like that possible for OS X Mail.app? I know the "Automatic detect" function but it doesn't seem to work particularly well beyond English (at least in my case).

Are there any plugins or anything like that?

Comment: You can choose the dictionary via Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar.

Comment: When using "automatic", did you first go the Setup item at the bottom of the list and check the boxes for the languages you normally use?

Comment: @TomGewecke yes, I kept only the languages I use everything else is unchecked